# Print "open curly bracket" with lua

Tags: lua, curly-braces

I'm new to lua and I'm trying to print an open curly bracket `{` in the output screen. I tried these ones:

```
print "%{"

print "\u123"

print "{{"
```

And there was no luck, but if I try the close bracket there's no problem and it prints `}`.

I'm wondering how may I figure it out.

Comment: Try `print(string.char(123))` or `print("\123")`

Comment: Doesn't `print "{"` work?

Comment: Is there some reason you didn't expect `print "{"` to work? *Does* it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

`print "{"` Should do the job.

@lhf already sugested.

Comment: Yes it should work but I find out the reason was somewhere else in the code. A `grep -v "{"` were existed  and caused this.